Connect definition of 1st-order Wasserstein distance given CDFs and general definition of Wasserstein distance
In this post, the definition of the 1st-order Wasserstein distance is
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |F_1 (x)-F_2(x)| dx$
In Wikipedia, I see something completely different.
How do I connect the 2 definitions?

The second definition is more general as it applies to any complete metric space $X$ with metric $d$. The first "definition" is a special case that is only true when $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $d(x,y) = |x-y|$. This has to do with the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is totally ordered and probability measures can be uniquely identified with monotone nondecreasing functions given by the CDF. A statement and proof of is given by Proposition 2.17 of Santambrogio's book, which characterizes general optimal transport costs over $\mathbb{R}$:

Given $\mu$, $\nu\in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R})$, consider the cost $c(x,y) = h(x-y)$, where $h$ is a convex function. Then, we have $$ \mathscr{T}_c(\mu,\nu) = \int_0^1 h(F_\eta^{[-1]} - F_\mu^{[-1]})\mathrm{d}\mathscr{L}^1. $$ If $h(z) = |z|$, then this also coincides with $\int_\mathbb{R} |F_\mu(t)-F_\nu(t)|~\mathrm{d}t$.

The first part of the theorem comes from the representation of optimal transport maps over $\mathbb{R}$ in terms of pseudo-inverses of CDFs and the second part comes from change of variables and Fubini's theorem.
Santambrogio, Filippo, Optimal transport for applied mathematicians. Calculus of variations, PDEs, and modeling, Progress in Nonlinear Differential Equations and Their Applications 87. Cham: Birkhäuser/Springer (ISBN 978-3-319-20827-5/hbk; 978-3-319-20828-2/ebook). xxvii, 353 p. (2015). ZBL1401.49002.

Could you please explain what you mean by d(x,y)=|x−y|?

On a metric space, $d(x,y)$ is a function that computes the distance between the points $x$ and $y$.

OK, thanks. Suppose that I just want to focus on 2 random variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$, with support sets in the real numbers (nothing complex). I want to use Definition #1 to compute the Wasserstein distance. Are there any conditions or caveats that I need to be aware of, or can I just apply that definite integral on the two CDFs and get what I want?

Yes, that should give you exactly what you want

Thank you. You are very helpful!
